# How to get parameters from XML and execute the list of exe?

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am executing an exe with parameters like follows (I am using powershell).

```
$path="C:\Program Files\RobWare\RVTools"


$VCServer="15.3.3.3"
$VCServer2="16.5.4.4"
$AttachmentFile=$vcserver.xls

&"$path\rvtools.exe" -s $VCServer -u user-p password-c ExportAll2xls -d $AttachmentDir -f $AttachmentFile
&"$path\rvtools.exe" -s $VCServer2 -u user2 -p password123 -c ExportAll2xls -d $AttachmentDir -f $AttachmentFile
```

As i am having many VCserver, I thought it is better to have XML file and then execute this exe for all the VCserver.

I would like to write an xml file where all the parameters would be specified like follows.

```
<Host>
  <IP>15.3.3.3</IP>
  <User>user</User>
  <Password>password</Password>
</Host>

<Host>
  <IP>16.3.3.3</IP>
  <User>user</User>
  <Password>password</Password>
</Host>
```

Then call the exe and pass this parameters from XML. How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using a XML file like this :

```
<rvToolsParams>
  <Host> 
    <IP>15.3.3.3</IP> 
    <User>user</User> 
    <Password>password</Password> 
  </Host> 
  <Host> 
    <IP>16.3.3.3</IP> 
    <User>user</User> 
    <Password>password</Password> 
  </Host>
</rvToolsParams>
```

Called here under `rvtools.xml` you can also do these ways :

```
$xml = [XML](Get-Content C:\temp\rvtools.xml)
$xml.rvToolsParams.host

IP                                      User                                    Password
--                                      ----                                    --------
15.3.3.3                                user                                    password
16.3.3.3                                user                                    password

$xml.rvToolsParams.host | % {& "$path\rvtools.exe" -s $_.IP -u $_.User -p $_.Password -c ExportAll2xls -d $AttachmentDir -f $AttachmentFile }
15.3.3.3
user
password
16.3.3.3
user
password
```

Or in a script

```
foreach ($host in $xml.rvToolsParams.host)
{
  $host.IP
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop through your XML file like this:

```
[xml] $xml = @'
<Hosts>
    <Host>
        <IP>15.3.3.3</IP>
        <User>user</User>
        <Password>password</Password>
    </Host>
</Hosts>
'@

$xml.SelectNodes('//Host') | % {
    & "$path\rvtools.exe" -s $_.IP -u $_.User -p $_.Password -c ExportAll2xls -d $AttachmentDir -f $AttachmentFile
}
```

This creates a XMLDocument object and uses an XPath query to get a collection of nodes that match the query and iterates through each one. PowerShell will make child nodes into properties of the node automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd build a hash table from the xml, and splat it.

```
$params = @{
   Server = $xml.Host.IP
   User = $xml.Host.User
   Password = $xml.Host.Password
    }
 &"$path\rvtools.exe" @params -c  ExportAll2xls -d $AttachmentDir -f $AttachmentFile
```